# How to highlight the fact that there's a "onmouse over" effect somewhere?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, tooltip, onmouseover

On my webpage I'll have a few circles with onmouse over effect (tool tips onmouse over). I suspect that most visitors will miss this and therefore was wondering what you usually do to drag visitors attention / highlight the fact that there's a onmouse over effect somewhere.

**edit:** to clarify, my question is "How can I give an indication to the visitor that there's a tooltip effect on an element"

Many thanks for your suggestions

Comment: You could hightlight the the elements that have a trigger, like an outer glow, changing their color, move them a little or something like that. Or you can blend in a sign that points towards the circles. You could trigger this if there's inactivity in a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the website of coding freak is very nice, I think he is searching for something that makes visible that there is something when hovering it with the mouse.

There are several solutions for your problem:
- Something slightly animated (not annonying), e.g. a pulsating button
- A monotone background and a clearly visible border or something like this around the hoverable element to convey that this area is special (like Bing does)
- Any kind of small text, symbols, etc.
- If they appear when hovering text, you can also format it (dotted underline, etc.)
- Some sort of glowing border (maybe it only glows when moving your mouse)
- ...

Finally, a hint:
To avoid misunderstandings, please clarify future questions so everyone is able to get their intention, since this one isn't really clear (at least to me, I'm not sure whether or not I'm covering what you want).

Answer (score 4):

This should be something your design/UX takes care of, drawing the users attention to specific elements in the page and general intended experience of the page.

Normally tooltips are marked with an icon (? etc), highlighted with text decoration or again an obvious part of the design, they're there to help the user, they can't use something they don't know is there.

If they are not information based and are interactive elements you could always apply a static state CSS animation to them (using a looping `@keyframe` animation), like making them subtly jingle, glow, move or highlight.

These elements should also be large enough for the user to see and interact with, but not overpower the rest of your website content unless they are the main feature, in which case they would definitely need to be obvious.

Most users are smart enough these days to explore a well decorated page, but the interactive elements need some sort of prominence or draw to them.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to use a tooltip plugin**, ***http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/*** This link has a  nice collection of tooltip plugins to choose from, depending on your needs for your emphasize on your website.

**If you want a tooltip to set manually,** set the div to position: relative, and create a div that is display: none; and position: absolute; (in the html side it must be between the tags of parent div) and create a jquery command with hover and toggle the tooltip.

Comment: This is not what the question is about.

Comment: The question is not clear, but as far as I can understand, he's asking how to make a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and apologies for not being clear, english is not my native language. These tooltip plugins are great but my question was more "How can I give an indication to the visitor that there's a tooltip effect on an element"?

Comment: @Greg no problem. You can use settimeout with an arrow on it which attracts attention to the button. http://jsfiddle.net/DxpUb/